# How do you write a protocol specifying the existence of an arithmetic operator in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Here's an example. Writing a function to multiply two doubles is pretty simple:

```
func MultiplyDoubles(_ x: Double, _ y: Double) {
    return x * y
}
MultiplyDoubles(3,5) // returns 15
```

But suppose I wanted to write a generic function to do this:

```
func MultiplyValues<T>(_ x: T, _ y: T) {
    return x * y //ERROR
}
MultiplyValues(3, 5)
```

But this throws an error: `Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to to 'T' operands`.

I understand that I'd need to write a protocol specifying that `*` can be applied to it, but how would I do this?

I tried doing:

```
protocol Multipliable {
    static func *(A:Multipliable, B: Multipliable) -> Multipliable
}
func MultiplyValues<T: Multipliable>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> Multipliable {
    return x * y
}
MultiplyValues(3, 5)
```

Although this returns the message

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:15:19: error: argument type 'Int' does not conform to expected type 'Multipliable'
MultiplyValues(3, 5)
                  ^
```

**Research:**
I've already looked at the documentation for [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) as well as the documentation for [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) and for [operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID28). I'm not writing a generic protocol, but rather a normal protocol that's meant to specify that it can be multiplied. This documentation explained how to overload operators, as well as how to create generic functions, and use protocols with generic functions, but none of them explained how to write a protocol specifying that an operator could be applied to the protocol.

Comment: Edit your question and discuss what you found when you googled for generic protocols, and why it wasn't helpful for you.

Comment: Rob's answer is just right IMO, but before you go too far this down this road, be sure to read https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/. "`*` can be applied to it" is not the same thing as "can be multiplied." If what you want is "can be multiplied" you need a protocol that defines the semantics for that (like Numeric does), not just the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the existing [`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) protocol:

```
func multiply<T: Numeric>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T {
    return x * y
}
```

---

But, let's imagine that such a protocol didn't exist. You can define your own and the specify which types conform to this protocol:

```
protocol Multipliable {
    static func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

// These types already implement the above method, so all you need to do
// is declare conformance to your protocol with an empty extension.

extension Int: Multipliable { }
extension Double: Multipliable { }

// repeat for other types as you see fit
```

And then you can do:

```
func multiply<T: Multipliable>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T {
    return x * y
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this.

```
protocol Multipliable {
    static func *(A:Self, B: Self) -> Self
}
extension Int : Multipliable {}
//You need other extensions for other numeric types...

func MultiplyValues<T: Multipliable>(_ x: T, _ y: T) -> T {
    return x * y
}

MultiplyValues(3, 5)
```

But current Swift has some numeric protocols and you should better utilize them (as in Rob's answer).